# Connecting MATLAB Database Toolbox to MSSQL using Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, matlab, jdbc, windows-authentication

I need to connect my MATLAB database toolbox to SQL Server, but MATLAB is returning the following error...

'This driver is not configured for integrated authentication.'

I'm new at this, but I've followed the instructions found at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx
&
http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9SHNAT/

I've added the full path to the 'sqljdbc4.jar' file to the end of the classpath.txt as follows...

- C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar

I've also added the full path to the 'sqljdbc_auth.dll' to the end of librarypath.txt as follows...

- C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\auth\x86

Note that I'm able to use windows authentication when interacting directly with the database through Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, but MATLAB continues to be stubborn.

I've tested various different writable locations for the 'sqljdbc4.jar' file and I've tested the auth file in both the x86 file and the x64 file, though I have 32-bit Java so I believe that the x86 should be correct.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the JDBC drivers DYNAMICALLY instead of STATIC using the javaaddpath function.  That worked for me.